# python Passing a range into a function

Tags: python

```
def my_function(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
print my_function(range(0,1,2)) # Add your range between the parentheses!
```

what I am doing wrong here? it won't return anything but zero.

Comment: What exactly is that supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working, you're just not passing a long enough input

```
range(0, 1, 2)
```

equals

```
[0]
```

And so

```
my_function(range(0,1,2))
```

equals

```
[0]
```

Try

```
my_function(range(10))
```

which equals

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

The [documentation for the `range` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) gives the signature as

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

So `range(0, 1, 2)` means "start at 0 and go to 1 in steps of 2" but the next item in the range after the start would be `2` which is more then the stop value, so isn't emitted.

Comment: O okay, thank you @Daniel, I was so stuck on what I was reading instead of actually doing what it was asking for. Thank you everyone for the input.